# (Android) Moto G stops debugging in a short time

Tags: android, debugging, motorola

I have Moto G, USB debugging works, but very strange:

when I try to debug code, 10-15 seconds after running was stopped on a breakpoint, **debugger is disconnecting**.

Never seen this before, is there any reason for that behaviour?
No special option ware set in Developer options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be a bad USB cable or bad contact in USB port (either on Moto side either on your PC side). Try to use another cable and/or USB port.

Comment: Yeah, seems to be that, I didn't think about it earlier, thanks )